# Mysql query showing extra fields

Tags: mysql

I am trying this query:

```
SELECT * FROM heath_check where cid = '1' and eid in('3','5','7','1','6')
```

My table structure:

[image]

I want distinct `eid` but all other data as it is. For example I have two entries with an `eid` of `1` my query fetched both, but I want one which is in the second column.

[image]

Comment: Please take care when tagging your questions - this has nothing to do with jQuery

Comment: I am sorry. I wanted to add query not jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM heath_check AS hc
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT MAX(id) AS lastId 
   FROM heath_check 
   WHERE cid = '1' and eid in('3','5','7','1','6')
   GROUP BY eid) AS lastIDs
ON hc.id = lastIDs.lastId
;
```

You need a subquery, like the above, to find the records you want for each value. If you had wanted the first ones, you could use `MIN(id)` instead; if you cannot count on sequential ids, it becomes much more complex with use of potentially non-unique timestamps (if they are even available).

Answer (score 0):

Create a `RowNumber` grouped by `eid` and filter the `RowNumber = 1` to get the expected result.

```
SELECT id, eid, cid,weight, s_blood_pressure
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY eid ORDER BY id DESC) AS RowNumber
    FROM heath_check 
    WHERE cid = '1' AND eid IN ('3','5','7','1','6')
) A
WHERE RowNumber = 1
```